# multiple this.setState(this.state) not re-rendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render, I have a function that updates the properties. I have listed the functions that get called between, but I think only the last one matters since it is the one that updates the data I use.

```
  <button 
    onClick={() =>
      this.handleUpdateProperty() 
    }>
    Update Properties 
  </button>
```

which calls:

```
  handleUpdateProperty = () => {
    this.getDataBC(); 
    this.setState(this.state);
//db.inventory.find( { status: "D" } )
  }
```

That in turns calls:

```
  getDataBC = () => {
    var rentals = scFunctions.getRents();
    console.log(web3.toAscii(rentals[1][0]));


    for(let i = 0; i < rentals[0].length; i++){
      let currentProp = {
        status: rentals[0][i].toNumber(),
        location: web3.toUtf8(rentals[1][i]).replace(/\s+/g,''),
        company: web3.toUtf8(rentals[2][i]).replace(/\s+/g,''),
        price: rentals[3][i].toNumber(),
        start: rentals[4][i].toNumber(),
        end: rentals[5][i].toNumber(),
        help: "haha"
      }
      console.log(currentProp)
      this.updateDB(currentProp);
    }
    this.getDataFromDb(); 
    this.setState(this.state);
  };
```

That in turn calls:

```
  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/property")
      .then(property => property.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }))
      .then(this.setState(this.state))
  };
```

The last function does the:

```
`.then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }))`
```

which updates the data I use to render my page. However, it doesn't update the page right away, I have to refresh the page to see the results from pressing the button. I thought
`.then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }))`
would rerender the page?

Thank you so much

edit:
The constructor is as follows:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      show: false, // show of the rental modal
      company: "Homeaway", 
      id: 0,
      message: null,
      intervalIsSet: false,
      idToDelete: null,
      idToUpdate: null,
      objectToUpdate: null,
      rentProperty: "DongFang",
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      firstName: "Ludwig",
      showConflict: true,
      lastName: "Wittgenstein"
    };
    this.handleCompanySubmit = this.handleCompanySubmit.bind(this);

  }
```

This is what uses the "data" from state. So I want this function to rerun and update the page when I setState...:

```
  renderProperties = data => {
    var properties = []
    var propRow = []
    data.forEach((property,index) => {
      propRow.push(<Col xs={{ size:3, offset: .5}}> 
        <Jumbotron>
          <Image src={require("./images/1.jpg")} fluid rounded />
          <b> {property.location} </b> 
          <h1> Price: {property.price} </h1> 
          <div> 
          {this.renderStatusButton(property)}
          </div>
        </Jumbotron> 
      </Col>)
      if((index+1)%3 == 0){ // if first in the row
        properties.push(<Row>{ propRow }</Row>)
        propRow = []
      }

    })
    return (
      <Container>
        {properties}
      </Container> 
    )
  }
```

And this is in the render:

```
   {this.renderProperties(data)}
```

I am going to bed. Thank you all for your help so far. If it doesn't get fixed, it is fine. It is not pivotal.

Comment: What are you expecting `this.setState(this.state);` would do?

Comment: Once you update the state with data from dB why are you updating the state again?

Comment: I am trying to force the page to rerender. I thought maybe the res-> this.setState stopped it from rerendering instead of just this.setState, but .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data })) works since my data does get updated. Just that I have to refresh page

Comment: @FranktheTank `setState` call will rerender your view automatically. In some edge cases there is `forceUpdate` function https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: @FranktheTank Do you have constructor to your component?  If yes please add code of it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you just want to refresh the page once the fetch in `getDataFromDb()` has finished, is that correct?
If so, you don't need all those `setState()` calls, you just need one in `getDataFromDb()`, which should be written as follow:

```
getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/property")
      .then(property => property.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }))
};
```

That is, you don't need the last `setState()` call you wrote neither.

Anyways, in `getDataBC()` I see two functions (`getRent()` and `updateDB`) that I don't know what they do, so maybe there are some problems in those functions too.